# Java files become messy code in intellij idea

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, file-encodings

I try import a project created by eclipse into intellij idea, and I have setted the file encode to UTF-8 in both eclipse and intellij idea, like this:

[image]

But there are all messy codes when I open a java file in intellij idea, like this:
[image]
What makes me confused is the xml file works well, no messy code as I considered.

Who can tell me what can I do to fix this case?

Comment: That doesn't look like a Java file at all, even with incorrect encoding it would not look as bad as that.

Comment: What does the `SecondTest.java` file look like in Eclipse?

Comment: Hi, @RobAu, the SecondTest.java file in Eclipse works well as usual.
package com.mew;

public class SecondTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, second");
    }
}

Sorry, I don't konw how to show you pictures in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @greg-449. But it's true. All I had done is  import a project created by Eclipse and then open a java file.

Comment: Can you right click the file in Eclipse to verify it uses UTF-8 encoding? (Right click in Project explorer -> Properties)

Comment: Hi, @RobAu. Unbelieveable, I think it's because of a security software which is installed claimed by my company. Sorry to bother you.